# Best practice thread safe circular linked list implementation in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading, list, linked-list

I implemented the circular linked list like this:

```
//  MonitoringDictionary is a ConcurrentDictionary<MonitorKey, LinkedList<MonitorValue>> 
var value = ProjectValues.MonitoringDictionary[key];
var monitorValue = new MonitorValue(filePath + "." + memberName + " line:" + lineNumber, executionTime);

if (value.Count >= 5000)
{
    value.RemoveLast();
    value.AddFirst(monitorValue);
}
else
{
    value.AddLast(monitorValue);
}
```

But sometimes when I try to execute this line: `value.RemoveLast();` it throws exception:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object. at
>   System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList`1.InternalRemoveNode(LinkedListNode`1
>   node) at Shared.WebService.Log.Monitoring(Double executionTime, String
>   filePath, String memberName, Int32 lineNumber)

So i decided to lock linked list before removing the last item like this:

```
lock (value)
{
    if (value.Count >= 5000)
    {
        value.RemoveLast();
        value.AddFirst(monitorValue);
    }
    else 
    {
        value.AddLast(monitorValue);
    }
}
```

But now I'm worrying about performance and dead end, so here are my questions:

1- Does locking linked list solve the problem?

2- Is there better practice to implement circular linked list?(performance is my first priority)

Thank you.

Comment: how can someone say your implemented list is thread safe or not when you didn't show your implemented list?

Comment: i don't get it!! i posted all my code. i have a ConcurrentDictionary<MonitorKey, LinkedList<MonitorValue>>. i try to add items into my  LinkedList<MonitorValue> untill they reach the maximun size which is 5000. then i remove the first one and add next to the list. if you need anything else just let me know. thank uou so much dear @M.kazemAkhgary

Comment: I'd be more concerned about correctness - it's an odd definition of "circular" in that the first 5000 items are ejected in reverse order - i.e. when you add items 5001 and 5002, you end up with the list like `5002, 5001, 1, 2, ... 4998`. Is that really what you're wanting?

Comment: dear @Damien_The_Unbeliever. yes. that's what i want. but why its odd?

Comment: It's odd because item 1, the very first item that was added, gets to survive 9998 subsequent adds. Item 5000 doesn't survive even a single subsequent add. Items 5001 and over all survive exactly 4999 subsequent adds. Normally, you'd expect to eject items in the same order as they're added so that they all have the same "survival" rate.

Comment: now i get it. i don't need them in order.

Comment: Your locking scheme looks sufficient for this part and it shouldn't be noticeable in performance. But you'll also have to lock when iterating that LinkedList, and that could be a problem.

Comment: thank you dear @HenkHolterman. locking during iterating sound like bad idea!!

Comment: So, together with the comments from @Damien you probably should take a step back and rethink your whole problem&solution here. This is an XY problem.